# Unable to click only few links on the site and rest other are clickable using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to display all the links from the google.com website and after displaying the links, I am trying to click each and every link on the site. My code is clicking all the links except

---

1) Advertising
2) Business
3) How search works

---

Please advise as other links on the website are getting clicked except the above ones.

My code -->

```
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"viewport\"]/div[3]/div/div/a[2]")).click();

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    System.out.println("Total links on the site :"+links.size());

    for(int i=0;i<links.size();i++)
    {
        String linksname=links.get(i).getText();
        if(!linksname.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println(linksname);
            //Thread.sleep(5000);
            links.get(i).click();
            driver.navigate().back();
            links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your locator actually find them? Are they in an IFRAME or something?

Comment: No, they are not inside any frame. If you look at the website - www.google.com, you will see these links are present at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

@Bimlesh Some elements in DOM might not be clickable by the time you try. Use "explicit wait" instead of Thread.sleep before you click. This will solve your problem.
Eg: 
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elementName));

Answer (score 0):

those links might not be present or clickable as others mentioned. use something like this:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

or even better

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
               .withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
               .pollingEvery(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
               .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
               .withMessage("Wait timed out after 10 seconds");

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.Id("..."))).click();
```